# I need to take max value from different id of database from $scope to others

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have this database:

[image]

I need to sort those child id(s) (from `type1` to `type10`), show sorted value at UI and the biggest value of id will be the new variable that I want to put that `$id` (example in this case the biggest value is `84.5` which has an `$id` named `type2`) to be `sifat="type2"`.

Should I declare them in a new variable and then sort it?

Comment: how are you retrieving values? we need to see that code to help you out

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do sorting on the client, but you can use angularfires `$firebaseArray` to get everything into an array at least:

```
$firebaseArray(...child('result')).$loaded().then(function(types){
    $scope.types = types;
})
```

And then sort in the dom (or wherever else you'll need too)

```
<div ng-repeat="type in types | orderBy:'value'"></div>
```

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray

Answer (score 0):

I solved this

```
 fireBaseData.refUser().child($scope.user_info.uid).child("result")
                  .orderByValue()
                  .limitToLast(1)
                  .on("value", function(snapshot){
                     snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                       console.log("The "+ data.key()+" score is "+ data.val());
                       $scope.highestval = data.val();
                       $scope.highesttype = data.key();

                       fireBaseData.refUser().child($scope.user_info.uid).update({    // set
                         sifat: $scope.highesttype
                       });
                     });
                  }
```

and also the filter function from @Mathew Berg is working as well, thanks